# How to preserve diacritics when cross-mounting drives to Windows7 and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, external-drive, diacritics

A friend backed up an in accessible Windows 7 partition to a big (close to 1TB) external USB drive using KNOPIX. Unfortunately the umlauts and accents in the file names of his extensive music collection now appear garbled (UTF8 vs ISO xxx, I guess) when he accesses that drive from Windows.

My guess is he needs to mount the two drives in a 'special way,' that takes the diacritics translation into account,  on KNOPIX? Or do you have another idea what went wrong?

This is the second part of a windows/linux problem I'm having. See [how-does-one-mount-a-partition-in-windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/331767/how-does-one-mount-a-partition-in-windows-7) for the other part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your system (Knoppix) is using **an Unicode-based locale (UTF-8):**

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf-8"
[skipped irrelevant settings]
LC_ALL=
```

If the `LANG` or `LC_CTYPE` variables do not end in `.utf-8` (or `.utf8`), fix them:

1. run `locale -a` and make sure it lists the needed locale (i.e. `en_US.utf-8`);
2. if the locale is not listed, uncomment it in `/etc/locale.gen`:

   ```
   en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
   ```

   and run `locale-gen` as root;
3. run `export LANG="en_US.utf-8"`
4. run `(xterm &)` or `(gnome-terminal &)` to start a new terminal with the new settings applied;
5. close the old terminal. (It is *not* enough to change $LANG for the current shell.)

In the new terminal, verify output of `locale` and check whether it fixes your problem.

**Also make sure your filesystem driver is using UTF-8.** The NTFS filesystem uses Unicode exclusively, but if you mounted it while having an incorrect locale, the driver might be in a translation mode. Unmount the filesystem and mount it again, while having a correct $LANG. If even that does not help, try adding the **`utf8`** and **`iocharset=utf8`** options to `mount`...

```
# mount -t ntfs -o utf8,iocharset=utf8 /dev/foo /mnt
```

...or switch to the **ntfs-3g** driver:

```
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/foo /mnt
```